# Is it possible to break a mirelurk's shell to make it more vulnerable

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4 you can focus on limbs/body parts of the enemy to cripple them. Each body part has a health bar and it is crippled whenever the bar is depleted.

I was wondering if you can cripple any mirelurk's shell so it is as vulnerable when shooting its shell as if you were shooting its face. I've never been able to get the shell's health to 0.

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question, but as a recommendation for fighting Mirelurks- I don't think their shells mitigate DOT effects. For example, if you have Pickman's Blade, Mirelurks will bleed out pretty quickly, even if you're hitting their shells.

Comment: Explosive shotgun to legs tend to kill everything.  Explosive minigun kills even yourself...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to be possible with minelurks that have high health:
https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/4qjefy/i_managed_to_knock_the_shell_off_of_a_mirelurk/

But, it seems way simplier to aim for their legs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't have any pictures to back this up, as all of my mirelurks are dead and their corpses have either been eaten or worse. But to answer your question, it is possible to break their shells.

I normally run a raider build, with a combination of shotguns, flamers, and plasma weapons that I liberate from recently deceased gunners. The flamers are used to break the mirelurks legs down, extremely quickly. But to answer your question of the shell. I've found that shotguns, particularly the combat gun, maxed out with mods, and the plasma sniper rifle; Have the best hope of destroying their shells.